# Subinterface in Windows

Tags: windows, networking

Does anybody know how to add a network subinterface in Windows? Something like eth0:1 in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Like a second virtual adapter? of course. Since you haven't specified your version of Windows, I'll tell you the XP way. The only difference in configuration between XP and newer versions is **how to get to your network connections**, but I assume you know how to do that :)

- Right click on your connection in Network Connections and go to **Properties**, you will see a dialog like this:

[image]

- Ensure **Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)** is selected, and hit properties as shown above.
- If you aren't already using static addressing, grab your current network info from the command prompt using **ipconfig /all** and substitute it into this dialog:

[image]

- After you've filled in all the details, click the **Advanced** button at the bottom of the dialog shown above
- Near the top, under **IP Addresses**, click **Add** and specify the details of the new virtual interface in the dialog that pops up:

[image]

[image]

- Click OK on all windows, and you've got yourself a second IP bound to your network adapter!

Comment: This does bind a second IP address to a given interface, but it does not appear to create a subinterface to do so.  It appears that Windows does not support subinterfaces as such, but simply supports a different way of having multiple IP Addresses for a single NIC.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, but one virtual interface is supposed to use DHCP and if I enable DHCP I cannot add more static IPs. Also I don't think it will support routing between these networks (I'm not sure of this, but I am going to try now).